# What is the differences between focused and pressed on android Button?

Tags: java, android, button

I found a tutorial to create android custom button : 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#CustomButton

What is the differences between **pressed** and **focused**
And please tell me a focused condition on this button. because I couldn't find any condition which can make this button turned orange.

Comment: I assume you could focus the button by pressing down/up arrow keys on your device. As I can't verify it currently, you'll have to check yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can focus buttons without clicking them. This was a bug in a application i developed recently. I set them to be focusable: then the first click on them was just focusing the user on the button and the second was actually triggering the onClick event. This is not so good user experience, but I imagine there might be cases where this is useful.

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been answered here. Please thoroughly search stackoverflow, before posting a question: [android: what is the difference between focused, enabled, pressed, and selected states?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959478/android-what-is-the-difference-between-focused-enabled-pressed-and-selected)

I am basically pasting the answer here for your convenience.

"*Enabled -> User Interaction possible.
Disabled -> User interaction not possible.
    if you hover the mouse over a widget, it is focussed
    If you make a press-down (half click) on that widget, it is pressed
    If you press-down and press-up while the mouse is at the same position, it is selected*"

Comment: I already read it. But, still confused with focused on touch screen. Thanks

Comment: Hover the mouse over an android device??

Comment: @tm_forthefuture haha, on some android devices, like the N1, a trackball is available which can be used to move to different parts of the UI. The answer is applicable in that sense. But I agree, the 'hover the mouse' part is misleading