# the difference between android tab selected, pressed, focused?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm  trying to customize the `Actionbar` tab. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959478/android-what-is-the-difference-between-focused-enabled-pressed-and-selected), but it's still not clear to me

If I am making an app only for phone, should I still worry about focused and pressed?  And when you "**touch**" the tab, is it considered as pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to worry about focused and pressed only if you have some layers of view other way if you click with your finger it's press.