# Quick Settings Resets the State Of My Custom Button

Tags: android, button, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am trying to find out whether when you access quick settings the App knows or can be told.

I have a set of buttons that I am using as tabs (in a `Fragment`, in a `CardView)`, when I pull down the quick settings the button loses its state. I have tried several mechanisms to resolve it, but can't find a way.

The buttons use

```
.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { ... }
```

rather than the `onClick listener`.

I get the same effect when I try to set the state of the buttons before a dialog is shown, if I set the state after the dialog is dismissed in

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { ... }
```

I can then get the required behaviour.

I am missing something in my knowledge in terms of the way a dialog and hence the `quick settings` cause the underlying view to be updated or notified of a change.

Can anyone help.

Update:

the button xml is as follows

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/fs_btn_tab_month"
        style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/fs_btn_tab_month"
        android:textColor="@color/button_text_color" />
```

and button_default_bg is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="@color/text_white" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/text_white" />
        <corners
            android:radius="1dp" />

    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="@color/background" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/text_white" />
        <corners
            android:radius="1dp" />

    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

As far as setOnClickListener() vs setOnTouchListener(), I needed to set the state of the button so it looks like a tab, and be able to do that from elsewhere in the fragment, and I couldn't find a way to do that with setOnClickListener.

It looks like this

[image]

When I say loses its state it goes to its blue background color.

I set the "state" as follows

```
mDaySelectedButton.setPressed(false);
mMonthSelectedButton.setPressed(true);
mMonthSelectedButton.setElevation(0f);
mYearSelectedButton.setPressed(false);
```

It all works, apart from the quick settings pull down issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "lose its state", how does this state-loss look like or manifest? Is there a reason for using touchListener, when you're watching for clicks only anyway?

Comment: Capricorn, added more detail above.

Comment: I guess that in your screenshot the "month" button is in pressed_state and therefore has the white background? And when pulling down the notification center or quick settings panel from android, it returns to the "unpressed" look (purple/blueish background)?

Comment: Thats exactly the behaviour

Comment: I assume pressed views lose their state while loosing focus, what happens when the app get's overlayed by the notification center/quicksettings. Have you tried using "selected" state instead?

Comment: Genius, if you turn that into an answer I'll vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that when the notification center/quicksettings menu is pulled down, the buttons lose their "focused" state, as only one view can have the focus at a time. Check out [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959478/android-what-is-the-difference-between-focused-enabled-pressed-and-selected) for additional details about the different view states.

As you want to keep the selection of the button, try using selected state for that purpose.

However I would recommend taking a look at Android SDK's [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), as this encapsulates your desired functionality and would only require some styling to meet your screenshots. There also is a tutorial at [codepath.com](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout)